# How do I implement a "hand back" from Facebook Inbox once I "hand off" from my chatbot

Tags: facebook, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot, handoff

Building a chatbot and trying to implement the [handover protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol). SO far I have it handing off to the inbox, so that if someone asks for customer service, the bot hands over to the inbox and presumably someone who is monitoring the page can answer. Once the inbox is the primary receiver, I can't find a good way to hand it back to the bot ... I know that I can set a timer and have the bot request 
for the conversation to be handed back, but this does not seem like the best approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mark the chat as 'Done' in the Page inbox and thread control will be returned to the primary receiver app.

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in this functionality, but I was also wondering is there any way of monitoring whether a question has been answered after handing over to the inbox? So my chatbot can check and then take back control if it hasnt.

Comment: The bot only receives the incoming messages via webhook, not the outgoing ones. So to do what you are asking would probably requiring doing pulls on the /conversations endpoint. But since the point of passing to the Inbox is to enable manual control of the chat, probably best to trust the agent will pass thread control back when done.